# Django commands not running on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

My app works perfect locally, but when deploying yo heroku my commands to create records for my objects are not working.

For example, locally I've a command to create Category objects from reading a CSV file.

```
python manage.py samples
```

However, the tables are created in me PostgreSQL DB on Heroku when running:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

In my project I've a Procfile to call all my commands, but according to error they are not been executed:

```
File "D:\web_proyects\stickers-gallito-app\shop\views.py", line 94, in SamplePack
    slug=product_slug,
  File "D:\virtual_envs\stickers-gallito-app\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\virtual_envs\stickers-gallito-app\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 399, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
shop.models.Sample.DoesNotExist: Sample matching query does not exist.
```

**Procfile:**

```
release: python manage.py makemigrations
release: python manage.py migrate
release: python manage.py ubigeo_peru
release: python manage.py groups
release: python manage.py categories
release: python manage.py products
release: python manage.py products_pricing
release: python manage.py samples
release: python manage.py samples_pricing
web: gunicorn stickers_gallito.wsgi --log-file -
```

**settings.py**

```
import os

# SITE_ROOT = root()


# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '^_67&#r+(c+%pu&n+a%&dmxql^i^_$0f69)mnhf@)zq-rbxe9z'

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'stickers-gallito-app.herokuapp.com',
                 'stickersgallito.pe', 'www.stickersgallito.pe']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'shop',
    'search_app',
    'cart',
    'stripe',
    'order',
    'crispy_forms',
    'embed_video',
    'storages',
    'marketing',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'stickers_gallito.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
                 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'shop', 'templates/'),
                 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'search_app', 'templates/'),
                 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'cart', 'templates/'),
                 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'order', 'templates/'), ]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'shop.context_processor.menu_links',
                'shop.context_processor.has_shop',
                # 'cart.context_processor.current_time',
                'cart.context_processor.cart_items_counter'
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'stickers_gallito.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

if DEBUG:
    # Redirecciona www y http  a https
    SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False

    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }

else:

    # Redirecciona www y http  a https
    SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True

    ### HEROKU POSTGRESS ACCESS
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': 'd8ss9rgh1sbaj',
            'USER': 'knwpfelgydrsmq',
            'PASSWORD': 'dcd65707c2746bd6842d79773dedc944bf570b3ec27039a81dd715be213b85ef',
            'HOST': 'ec2-54-225-116-36.compute-1.amazonaws.com',
            'PORT': '5432'
        }
    }

####


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = False

USE_L10N = False

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.StaticStorage'

MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.MediaStorage'

####


MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'media')

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

### CULQUI ###


CULQI_PUBLISHABLE_KEY = os.environ['CULQI_PUBLISHABLE_KEY']

CULQI_SECRET_KEY = os.environ['CULQI_SECRET_KEY']

# DO NOT DO THIS!
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

MAILCHIMP_API_KEY = os.environ['MAILCHIMP_API_KEY']
MAILCHIMP_DATA_CENTER = os.environ['MAILCHIMP_DATA_CENTER']
MAILCHIMP_EMAIL_LIST_ID = os.environ['MAILCHIMP_EMAIL_LIST_ID']

### AMAZON ###


AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'Expires': 'Thu, 31 Dec 2099 20:00:00 GMT',
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=94608000',
}

AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ['AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME']
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = os.environ['AWS_S3_REGION_NAME']
# Tell django-storages the domain to use to refer to static files.
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']

### MAILGUN - EMAIL MESSAGE SETTINGS ###

EMAIL_HOST = os.environ['EMAIL_HOST']
EMAIL_PORT = os.environ['EMAIL_PORT']
EMAIL_USE_TLS = os.environ['EMAIL_USE_TLS']
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ['EMAIL_HOST_USER']
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ['EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD']
```

Comment: Did the release succeed?  You can check with [`heroku releases`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase#checking-release-status-logs).

Comment: BTW: it's generally a better idea to run makemigrations locally and check them in, that way the `migrate` command is doing the same thing remotely as it does locally

Comment: @RishiG I've ended up running all my commands locally (but to the Heroku PostgreSQL data).  What I don't know is if I should keep the commands in the Procfile file?

Comment: not `makemigrations` because that command generates migration files which should be checked in so that when you deploy, the files on Heroku are the same as the ones you have locally

Comment: I also wouldn't put all those object-creating management command calls in there, because you'd then end up creating all those objects (or trying to) every time you deploy.  What we usually do is either run object-creation manually through the shell after deployment or stick it into a manually-generated migration file so that it only runs once.

Comment: Could you post and example of both ways?

Comment: Or for example, how my Procfile should end and how the manually generated migration file should like and where to put it?

Comment: **You've leaked your database credentials!** If those are your real credentials you should invalidate them **_immediately_**. They are forever compromised, and you need to generate new ones. On Heroku you can do this by running [`heroku pg:credentials:rotate`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql-credentials#pg-credentials-rotate). Editing them out of your question is _**not enough**_.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be running all of those as release commands. You _definitely_ shouldn't be running `makemigrations`. By the time your code hits Heroku there shouldn't be any model changes to generate migrations. And your database won't be reset when you deploy a new version, so there's probably no need to run those commands that appear to seed the database.

Comment: Also, I _strongly_ urge you to use PostgreSQL on your development machine. SQLite and Postgres (and MySQL and others) aren't drop-in replacements for each other. It's very possible to have code that works with SQLite but blows up with Postgres. You want to discover this kind of thing as early as possible, not when you deploy to production.

Comment: And finally, I'm not sure that multiple `release` commands are a good idea. I can't find any documentation on what Heroku will do with these. It could run the first and ignore the rest, run the last and ignore the rest, run all of them in an unpredictable order, run them all in parallel, or anything else. Consider writing a "release script" if you really do need all of them and running that single script as your `release` command. (But again, I suspect that most of these shouldn't be executed for every release.)

Comment: @Chris ty. Where can I find documentation on writing a release script?

Comment: @OmarGonzales, I'm pretty sure just a regular shell script will work.